# Cannot fully delete ProgramData from Windows 8 installation within WinPE

Tags: windows, windows-8, permissions, winpe, programdata

I have a script that runs in WinPE that takes a system drive with Windows installed and deletes everything off of the drive (keeping the filesystem intact).

When dealing with a Windows XP/Vista/7 installation it functions properly. `attrib -S -A -H -I -R /S /D \` is run, and then everything is deleted.

However, within Windows 8, I run into an "Access Denied" error. For some reason, even as the SYSTEM user within WinPE, I can't edit the directory `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\LocationProvider`. I can't use `attrib` to set attributes, I can't delete it - I can't even `cd` into it! `dir /a` just returns `File Not Found`.

Using `rmdir /S /Q` gives me the "Access Denied" error.

Comment: Have you seen this on multiple systems, or just on one particular one?  In the latter case, there might be file system corruption.  In the former case it's probably a permissions issue, have you checked the ACL set on that directory?

Comment: Ah, to be honest, I am not sure how to check the ACL on the command line (this is WinPE, so there's cmd.exe only). This is apparent on every Windows 8 system I've dealt with - it's actually a software bug that I'm trying to fix (proprietary, can't show the code).

Comment: You could probably just check the permissions on that directory on a working system; they are unlikely different when the OS is shut down than when it is running.  But the command-line tool for checking permissions is `icacls.exe`; it isn't included in WinPE by default, IIRC, so you'll need to explicitly add a copy to your image, or put one on external media or a network share, or whatever.

Comment: You are correct, icacls.exe is not included in WinPE. That's the thing - it has to work with the current files, without a network connection, and without having any previous knowledge of the system. The only thing I can change is the program that runs and deletes the program. Any Win32API calls for ACL you'd recommend for ease of use?

Comment: The first step is to use icacls.exe on a single system to discover whether or not the permissions really are the problem.  If they are, it's not all that hard to deal with; it might just be a matter of enabling restore privilege.  But it may be that something else is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the problem is related to permissions and/or ownership, you can work around it using the built-in `robocopy` tool - luckily, this is included in Windows PE.

First, create an empty directory, e.g., `x:\empty` and then run

```
robocopy /e /purge /b x:\empty c:\
```

The `/b` flag tells robocopy to use backup mode, which bypasses security.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. You need to [take ownership](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html) first, for example using `takeown.exe`. Then fix permissions, for example using `icacls.exe`. Then proceed as you wish with copy, move, delete.